# How to change the color of a word that was replaced

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, colors, uitextview

Think of a grammar checker. If I type in "I should of known the show was today." it would make it into "I **should have** known it was today." There is a grammar checker app that will make the replaced part into the color red. I want to know how to do that.

BEFORE you link me to some other question, I've seen them, and they all talk about range. Range requires a set amount of characters that must be put, but you can see how this is a problem when you have over 100 phrases that would change if they were corrected. I keep seeing NSMutableString but that also has range.

For example, here is the code that turns the user input(whatever he types in) into a string.

```
NSString *input = _inputTextView.text;
```

And here is an example of a word that is being changed.

```
inpput = [input stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:@"(?wi)\\bshould of\\b" withString:@"should have" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [input length])];
```

And this is the code that makes the corrected string show in another UITextView:

```
_outputTextView.text = input;
```

For example:
User input: I should of gone to the store.
Output: I **should have** gone to the store.

Basically in the easiest way possible, is there a code I can put inside the [] on the above code to change the color? Like an options: color: or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one interested me so I worked out a quick solution to it.

I tested this and it seems to work pretty well. You need to use attributed strings in order to store the color attributes.

```
// define what you want to replace and what you want to replace it with
NSString *stringToReplace = @"(?wi)\\bshould of\\b";
NSString *newString = @"should have";

// get a mutable attributed string so that the color can be used as an attribute
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedInput = _inputTextView.attributedText.mutableCopy;

NSRange rangeToReplace;

do
{
    // check for occurrence
    rangeToReplace = [[attributedInput string] rangeOfString:stringToReplace options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
    if(rangeToReplace.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        // create the range we're going to color
        NSUInteger locationToBeReplaced = rangeToReplace.location;
        NSUInteger replacedLength = newString.length;
        NSRange rangeToAddAttribute = NSMakeRange(locationToBeReplaced, replacedLength);

        // replace old string
        [attributedInput replaceCharactersInRange:rangeToReplace withString:newString];

        // color new string
        [attributedInput addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:rangeToAddAttribute];
    }
}
while(rangeToReplace.location != NSNotFound); // continue until all occurrences have been replaced
```

Comment: I tried implementing this, but it kept freezing and wouldn't work. I tried it on a new file, and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Here's a very basic working implementation I put together: http://cl.ly/2m180W3F323h Just unzip it and run it.

Comment: This is a pretty neat approach, and a bit different then what I thought about. Thanks a lot! Now I need to implement it into 2 different UITextViews. The first text view will show the normal phrase, and the second one will show the new phrase. Thanks again so much!